# Assembly of variable-size stack frame: these stack-alignment instructions seem useless in allocating a VLA?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, callstack, stack-frame

I'm reading Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective 3rd edition and the assembly in `3.10.5 Supporting Variable-Size Stack Frames, Figure 3.43` confuses me.

The part of the book is trying to explain how a variable-size stack frame is generated and it gives a C code and its assembly version as an example.

Here is the code of C and assembly(Figure 3.43 of the book):

I don't know what the use of **line 8-10** in the assembly is. Why not just use `movq %rsp, %r8`after line 7?

**(a) C code**

```
long vframe(long n, long idx, long *q) {
    long i;
    long *p[n];
    p[0] = &i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = q;
    return *p[idx];
}
```

**(b) Portions of generated assembly code**

```
vframe:
2:    pushq    %rbp
3:    movq     %rsp, %rbp  
4:    subq     $16, %rsp
5:    leaq     22(, %rdi, 8), %rax      
6:    andq     $-16, %rax       
7:    subq     %rax, %rsp
8:    leaq     7(%rsp), %rax
9:    shrq     $3, %rax
10:   leaq     0(, %rax, 8), %r8
11:   movq     %r8, %rcx
................................
12: L3:
13:   movq     %rdx, (%rcx, %rax, 8)
14:   addq     $1, %rax
15:   movq     %rax, -8(%rbp)
16: L2:
17:   movq     -8(%rbp), %rax
18:   cmpq     %rdi, %rax
19:   jl       L3
20:   leave
21:   ret
```

Here is what I think:

After line 7, the `%rsp` should be a multiple of 16 (`%rsp` should be a multiple of 16 before `vframe` is called because of stack frame alignment. When `vframe` is called, `%rsp` is subtracted by 8 to hold the return address of the caller, and then the `pushq` instruction in line 2 subtracts `%rsp` by another 8, and in line 4 a 16. So at the start of line 7, `%rsp` is a multiple of 16. In line 7, `%rsp` is subtracted by `%rax`. Since line 6 makes `%rax` a multiple of 16, the result of line 7 is setting `%rsp` a multiple of 16) **which means the lower 4 bits of `%rsp` are all zeros.**
Then in line 8, `%rsp+7` is stored in `%rax`, and in line 9 `%rax` is shifted right logically by 3 bits, and in line 10, `%rax*8` is stored in `%r8`.

After line 7, the lower 4 bits of `%rsp` are all zeros. In line 8 `%rsp+7` just makes the lower 3 bits all ones, and line 9 truncates these 3 ones, and in line 10 `%rax*8` makes the result shift left by 3 bits. So the final result should just be the original `%rsp` (the result of line 7).

So I wonder whether line 8-10 are useless.

Why not just use `movq %rsp, %r8` after line 7 and remove the original line 8-10?

Comment: Hey @NameNull. It is highly unlikely to get a person reading/having the book you mentioned. And people won't go to extremes like finding the book to only answer your question. So it is rather better to provide all the relevant info here which one would see in the book. Hope you have read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link.

Comment: @RC0993, what information do you think is missing? The question seems complete to me.

Comment: NameNull, your analysis is correct. This is not very good code. The only thing I can think of is that the compiler has some common code sequences that it uses for alignment whether needed or not and there’s no impetus to optimize variable-size arrays, since they’re not commonly used.

Comment: @RC0993 I didn't indicate the book to be read, and therefore I edited my question to clarify it.

Comment: @prl I find that, in one practice problem of the book I mentioned, it gives me some specific values of %rsp at the end of line 4 and then asks me to compute the values of following modified registers. And those given values of %rsp are not all multiples of 16. So I guess the book does not assume %rsp at the end of line 7 to be multiples of 16. And the solution says the purpose of line 8-10 is to align %r8 to multiples of 8 so that the array of pointers is aligned(%r8 is the address of the array), which makes sense if %rsp is not a multiple of 16.

Comment: Yes, this is useless and weird.

I was able to repro the book's asm output with gcc4.8.5 `-Og`.  (`-O1` optimizes away the store/reload of `i` in the loop because `p[i]` can't actually alias onto `i`, even though they're both `long`)  https://godbolt.org/z/qwQxBu.  So unlike some other CS:APP examples, this isn't a case of the authors editing in fake GCC output and getting it wrong.  This insanity is real. And the instruction's you're asking about are present even at `-O2`, and even in current GCC9.2!!  Yes, pretty obvious missed optimization because sizeof(long) <= stack alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that a useful exploratory program would be to reduce your generated code to:

```
.globl _vframe
_vframe:
    pushq    %rbp
    movq     %rsp, %rbp  
    subq     $16, %rsp
    leaq     22(, %rdi, 8), %rax      
    andq     $-16, %rax       
    subq     %rax, %rsp
    leaq     7(%rsp), %rax
    shrq     $3, %rax
    leaq     0(, %rax, 8), %r8
    mov %r8, %rax
    sub %rsp, %rax
    leave
    ret
```

Note that I just eliminated the code that did anything useful, and returned the difference between %r8 and %rsp.
Then wrote a driver:

```
extern void *vframe(unsigned long n);


#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < (1<<18); i++) {
        void *p = vframe(i);
        if (p) {
            printf("%d %p\n", i, p);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to check it out.   They were always the same.  So, why?   It may be that it is a standard code emission when confronted with a given construct (var len array).  The compiler has to maintain certain standards, such as traceable call frames and alignment, os might just emit this code as the known solution to that.  Variable length arrays are generally considered a mistake in the language; a tribute to c++, adding a half-working, half-thought-out mechanism to C; so compiler implementors might not give to much attention to the code generated on their behalf.

Comment: Your test caller will always have RSP 16-byte aligned before a call.  It looks like that VLA allocation code is aligning the array address to `alignof(long*)`, in case RSP was not even aligned by 8.  That's insane, and current GCC still does that.  Maybe it's boilerplate left over from 32-bit mode (where GCC wants 8-byte alignment for int64_t on a 4-byte aligned stack on e.g. Windows), or from the possibility of array elements with alignof() > stack alignment?  But yes your test proves that given the ABI guarantee of 16-byte RSP alignment, that stuff is redundant for an array of `long*`.

Comment: my screed about VLAs being a codegen backwater is a bit like how “aam” was the most stable source for guessing cpu frequency before rdtsc.   Yeah, its there, but nobody really cares how well it works.

Comment: VLAs were initially intended for better handling multidimensional arrays. And they work great there. The capability of variable lenght stack allocation was just a side feature which somehow got so popular and infamous that it blinded people what VLAs are really for. `std::vector` is not a replacement for VLAs. Those are orthogonal features.